# VBA (Word) - Footer shapes collection contains both footer and header shapes

Tags: vba, ms-word

My document has only one header / footer type - `wdHeaderFooterPrimary`, constant = 1. I try to interact with shapes from footer, but collection contains also shapes from header.

I could distinguish which one is from header and which one from footer by `.top` property, but for so many elements and thousands of files it would take ages.

Is there any other way I can refer only to footer shapes?

```
Dim shp as Object

For Each shp in ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).Shapes
    debug.print shp.name
Next shp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.ShapeRange
```

Comment: Turned out my macro was iterating over all 998 shapes for -every- header/footer in a 100 page document. This change lowered that to about 4 or 5 iterations per head/footer and massively improved the speed